# Remove Method in HashTable

Tags: java, hashtable

Hi I'm working on an assignment about hash table. Everything is fine except for the remove method.
Here's code:

```
public boolean remove(K key) throws HashTableException {
    //
    //IMPLEMENT THIS FUNCTION
    //
    if (key == null)
        throw new HashTableException("Null keys not allowed in the hash table");

    int index = getIndex(key);
    HashTableNode<K,V> node = FindNode(key,index);
    if (node == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (node.getNext() == null) {
            node = null;
        } else {
            node = node.getNext();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

It doesn't remove the key at all. Can anyone help me please? thank you!

Comment: Be sure that the equals and hashcode methods for the Object being used as key are overridden.

Comment: Where do you do the actual remove? You just set a pointer that you have to `null` or reassign it, this doesn't affect the hash bucket that your got the pointer from. You don't need to wrap your code in an `else` if you have a `return`. Please format your code. Please stick to Java naming conventions - methods should be in lowerCamelCase.

Comment: I guess you have hash table with buckets. So in this case you should find root (not element you want to remove) element in bucket by key then iterate through this linked list and remove item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node = null; does not "delete" the node, it just sets the value of the variable node in this method to null. It does nothing to the actual node that is in the hashtable somewhere.

And in the next "else" you then have  node = node.getNext(); which, again, only change the node variable in this method. But since you return from the method without doing anything more with this variable, all this does is nothing since node is a local variable that only exists in this method.

You should read up on the concepts of local variables and references in java, which would probably lead to an understanding of why this is not working :)

Comment: Hi Plux, what you said really made a lot of sense. I'm not a CS major and just trying to learn some coding skills. In this class, we have a table[] which is an array of HashTalbe<K,V>. I just still don't know how to implement the actual remove

Comment: Glad it made a lot of sense. If you supply more of the code in this class it could be easier to directly suggest changes that would remove the node. Knowing the data is stored in an array, I can think of several different ways to implement this, and they require you to implement the remove function differently.

Answer (score 1):

node = node.getNext();

By this line, I think you are just traversing instead of re-writing the Next pointer

Maybe you should try node.getPrev().setNext = node.getNext();
if you can find the previous node and be able to set the next node.

Comment: This only changes the local variable and does nothing to the actual table.

Comment: This will remove the node from the linked structure

Comment: Nope. It will just change the reference in the local variable node to the next node in the linked structure. It does not change the actual structure.

Comment: Do you mean node = node.getNext()? Yes. That is what I said in my answer if you missed it.  By setNext() it means it is changing the link of the next part if you did not get it

Comment: Hmm, Im not really sure that I read correctly yesterday. Today I see you wrote getPrev().setNext, sorry about that. O.o That was weird. And you didn't edit that in just now or something? :P

Comment: I voted up your answer because I thought the same and now you should be able to guess that I did not edit it

Comment: =) that was more of a joke to excuse my blindness, if you had edited it I could have seen the revision history. I can not see who it is that has voted for my answer though. However, I did vote for yours also when I saw what you actually wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure hashcode() and equals() are overridden correctly.